# How to Add Time to the Text Of A Div (Time Value)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this code and let me know how I can add 30 minuts to the text in side a div like this

```js
 $(".matchtime div").each(function(){
       var current = $(this).text();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="text-left matchtime">
  <div>
    18:40
  </div>
</td>
<td class="text-left matchtime">
  <div>
    18:00
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: how you are getting the time?

Comment: it is fixed text

Comment: What have you done so far, what has your research turned up? What specific part(s) of this are you having trouble with? Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use date :

```
 $(".matchtime div").each(function () {
    var current = $(this).text();
    current = current.split(":");
    date = new Date();
    date.setHours(parseInt(current[0]));
    date.setMinutes(parseInt(current[1]) + 30);
    plus_30 = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes();
    console.log(plus_30);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using `Date` and `getMinutes` to add minutes address your problem.

```js
$(".matchtime div").each(function() {
  var dt = new Date();
  var dt1 = new Date(dt);
  dt1.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + 30);
  var time = dt1.getHours() + ":" + dt1.getMinutes() + ":" + dt1.getSeconds();
  var current = $(this).text(time);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-left matchtime">
      <div>
        18:40
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="text-left matchtime">
      <div>
        18:00
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```